# Why when transposing a matrix indicates non-conformable array - even when dimensions remain the same

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to understand the reason for the "non-conformable arrays" message I'm getting when dividing all elements of a matrix with a vector.

After creating the following objects:

```
test <- matrix(1:4, 2)
test1 <- 1:2
```

Dividing test/test1 yield:

```
  X1 X2
1  1  3
2  1  2
```

Transposing the vector doesn't change the result.

test/t(test1)

```
  X1 X2
1  1  3
2  1  2
```

Transposing the matrix and not the vector works:

```
t(test)/test1
   [,1] [,2]
X1  1.0    2
X2  1.5    2
```

But transposing both indicates that they are not conformable.

```
t(test)/t(test1)
```

> Error in t(test)/t(test1) : non-conformable arrays

I solved my problem the following way converting the transposed matrix as a data.frame:

```
as.data.frame(t(test))/t(test1)
   V1 V2
X1 1.0  2
X2 1.5  2
```

In this case the result is similar to transposing the matrix and not the vector.

Why is that? What am I missing here?

Comment: replicate the vector and it should work `test/test1[col(test)]`

Comment: Thanks. This helped.